# "low vibration disturbance" in tech text

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, technical-terminology

Could you help me with a translation of *low vibration disturbance* in German?

> low vibration disturbance, because of small, light, and lower power consumption equipment

Could I translate it as *niedrige Vibrationsstörung*?

Comment: Did you look the words up in a dictionary or try the whole sentence in a tool like DeepL? Please try first to answer your question with the classical tools, and if they aren't sufficient, tell us, what you found and why the answer is still open.

Comment: Welcome to German SE! I fixed some spelling and punctuation in the English version of your sentence; it's hard to translate something when the original isn't correct. For future reference, it's best to have include a full sentence for context. You can't translate *bear* into German, or *sein* into English without context.

Comment: @userunknown I looked up in dict.cc

Comment: As pointed out already by RDBury: more context is needed to find a good translation. It might matter whether the object in question is resilent to vibrations or cause of vibrations - something not clear from the snippet you provide.

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult to answer due to lack of context. It must be clear, which of these two cases applies:

- the described device is emitting low vibrations which would disturb other devices (then *vibrationsarm* would be my word of choice)
- the described device is resilient against vibrations of other sources (phrase suggestions: *vibrationsfest*, *hohe Vibrationsfestigkeit* [thanks to @Bodo] *unempfindlich gegenüber Vibrationen* or *geringe Anfälligkeit gegenüber Vibrationen*)

In any case I would avoid *Vibrationsstörung*, which supposedly would be interpreted as a fault caused by vibration.

Comment: Suggestions for the second case: *vibrationsfest* or *hohe Vibrationsfestigkeit*